# How does getblocktemplate select transactions?

Tags: transaction-selection, getblocktemplate, coin-age-priority

I wrote a script that compares the transactions listed in the **memory pool** with the transactions included in `getblocktemplate`:

http://learnmeabitcoin.com/explorer/node/memorypool

*(I've ordered the transactions by [current priority], and highlighted the ones included in `getblocktemplate` in blue.)*

- How does `getblocktemplate` choose which transactions to include from the memory pool in a candidate block?
- Why aren't transactions being selected from highest to lowest priority?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole mempool won't fit in a block; `getblocktemplate` returns enough transactions for a block. Blocks are, by default, [limited to 750kb by policy](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/a6a860796a44a2805a58391a009ba22752f64e32/src/policy/policy.h#L18), but many miners increase the size to the block limit of 1mb (which can be done by command-line flag).

The specific piece of code that decides on the transactions that should be included in a block [can be found here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/86b800c6a299455580fe76e5fb43218f0222e179/src/miner.cpp#L113). It's reasonably well documented, and not terrible to read, I'd suggest taking a look through it to see where your script operates differently.